# Django and CSRF protection for mobile apps

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am using Django + Django REST Framework + Django OAuth Toolkit.

I understand that AJAX calls from a web session require CSRF protection, but it is my understanding that mobile apps don’t as the very thing CSRF check are protecting against can’t happen in a dedicated app. If a person has an OAuth token, they are not using our web app so it seems I don’t need to perform CSRF checks in that case.

Is there any way to disable CSRF checks on REST Framework endpoints when a request includes an OAuth token, and if so is this a safe thing to do? Or should *all* requests be protected by the CSRF mechanism regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using [DRF's token authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) with a mobile app.  Initially, the user logs in to your backend with a username and password and then the backend issues a token for that instance of the mobile app, which [securely] stores the token locally.  With token authentication and the reality of sending your credentials (over SSL/HTTPS) to the server on every request, you obviate the need for a CSRF check and thus no CSRF check is done.

Comment: Excellent, I had completely missed the significance of their mechanism and thought I needed OAuth when in fact I didn't. Thanks!